# Oracle SQL Triggers

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I'm new to Oracle and SQL and I'm trying to create a trigger where the req_ship_date (suborder table) cannot be before the order_date (customer_order table). I created the trigger:

```
create or replace trigger req_ship_date_error
before insert on suborder
for each row
declare
placed_date date;
req_date date;
begin
select order_date into placed_date
from customer_order;
select req_ship_date into req_date
from suborder
where suborder_no = :new.suborder_no;
if placed_date > req_date then
raise_application_error(-20002, ('Order ' || :new.suborder_no || ' required shipping date cannot be before order date'));
end if;
end;
```

But even after a try inserting a good statement I'm getting the following error

```
insert into suborder
values  ( 8, 2, '10-jul-2012', '12-jul-2012', 'CVS', 2);
```

ERROR

```
    Error starting at line 1 in command:
insert into suborder
    values  ( 8, 2, '10-jul-2012', '12-jul-2012', 'CVS', 2)
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
ORA-06512: at "COMPANY.REQ_SHIP_DATE_ERROR", line 5
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'COMPANY.REQ_SHIP_DATE_ERROR'
01422. 00000 -  "exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows"
*Cause:    The number specified in exact fetch is less than the rows returned.
*Action:   Rewrite the query or change number of rows requested
```

Any idea what is causing this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- As @Shine points out, you need to have a `WHERE` clause on the query against `CUSTOMER_ORDER`
- A row-level trigger on `SUBORDER` cannot then query `SUBORDER`.  If you do that, you'll end up getting a mutating table error in general.  Assuming that `SUBORDER_NO` is the primary key of `SUBORDER`, however, you shouldn't need to query the table.  Simply use the `:new.req_ship_date` value you have in your hand.

Something like this should work assuming that the primary key of `customer_order` is `order_no` and that `order_no` exists in the `suborder` table.

```
create or replace trigger req_ship_date_error
  before insert on suborder
  for each row
declare
  l_placed_date date;
begin
  select order_date 
    into l_placed_date
    from customer_order
   where order_no = :new.order_no;
  if l_placed_date > :new.req_ship_date 
  then
    raise_application_error(
      -20002, 
      'Order ' || :new.suborder_no || ' required shipping date cannot be before order date');
  end if;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're **missing a where clause** on the first trigger's SELECT query:

```
 select order_date into placed_date
  from customer_order;
```

Will returns many row, so Oracle doesn't know which one to choose the date from (to place it inside `placed_date` variable). `INTO` clause always requires a single row.

Add a where clause so that a single result is returned.

Comment: I added : where order_no = :new.order_no; and i'm getting this: Warning: execution completed with warning
trigger req_ship_date_error Compiled.

Comment: You have to be sure that order_no is UNIQUE, so that it won't give you TOO_MANY_ROWS in the future. As for warning, you should see into logfiles but I wouldn't worry about that